# MIDI messages in Python are confusing?

Tags: python, midi, mido

I am currently working on the MIDI data set maestro-v2.0.0 ([see](https://magenta.tensorflow.org/datasets/maestro)).

I load my files in python with `from mido import MidiFile`
Then I work on the files from the data set (for example on `2009/MIDI-Unprocessed_07_R1_2009_04-05_ORIG_MID--AUDIO_07_R1_2009_07_R1_2009_04_WAV.midi`).
If I sort the event-on (velocity not zero here) messages with respect to the time then I get (for the first 10 messages):

```
message note_on channel=0 note=62 velocity=53 time=0,

message note_on channel=0 note=66 velocity=58 time=0,

message note_on channel=0 note=62 velocity=72 time=0,

message note_on channel=0 note=71 velocity=60 time=0,

message note_on channel=0 note=78 velocity=61 time=0,

message note_on channel=0 note=54 velocity=55 time=0,

message note_on channel=0 note=72 velocity=53 time=0,

message note_on channel=0 note=71 velocity=61 time=0,

message note_on channel=0 note=73 velocity=67 time=0,

message note_on channel=0 note=66 velocity=13 time=0
...
```

As you can see there are multiple notes played in the very first moment.
At the same time, I find these `note_on` events with the same pitches with `velocity=0`. I read somewhere that `note_on` with `velocity=0` corresponds to event-off tokens, i.e. the note is released.
I just wonder what is going on, why do my data look so "ugly"?
And when I say ugly I mean why have the midi files notes included which are not played. A note is not played if there is a `note_on` event at time `t` with `velocity>0` but at the same time there is a `note_on` of the same pitch at the same time with `velocity=0`. This unnecessary messages could have been simply omitted, we don't need to say that a note isn't played. This is what happens in the midi-files (in regard of my code). I hope it's clear what I mean.

My code can be inspected here

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as  np
from mido import MidiFile

def openJSON():
    path = "C:\\Users\\Bunlong\\PycharmProjects\\midiPreprocessing\\midi\\maestro-v2.0.0"
    path = os.path.realpath(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    filename = 'maestro-v2.0.0.json'
    with open(filename, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    return data


def openMidi(folderNr, fileNr):
    data = openJSON()
    folder = data[folderNr]['year']
    name = data[fileNr]['midi_filename']
    mid = MidiFile(name)
    return mid

def getRepresentation(mid):
    MAX_NOTE = 127
    noteOn_sequence = []
    noteOff_sequence = []
    time = []
    for i, track in enumerate(mid.tracks):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        print('Track {}: {}'.format(i, track.name))
        for msg in track:
            a = msg
            print(msg)
            if(a.type != 'control_change'):
                if (a.type == 'note_on'):
                    if (a.velocity == 0):
                        noteOff_sequence.append(a)
                    else:
                        noteOn_sequence.append(a)
                    time.append(a.time)

    #Sorting noteOff and noteOn sequence with respect to the timestamp
    indexPermutatationOn = sorted(range(len(noteOn_sequence)), key=lambda k: noteOn_sequence[k].time)
    indexPermutatationOff = sorted(range(len(noteOff_sequence)), key=lambda k: noteOff_sequence[k].time)

    sortedOn = []
    for index in indexPermutatationOn:
        sortedOn.append(noteOn_sequence[index])

    sortedOff = []
    for index in indexPermutatationOff:
        sortedOff.append(noteOff_sequence[index])


#call of methods
midiFile = openMidi(0,5)
getRepresentation(midiFile)
```

My goal is to represent the data as follows. If for a given timestamp *t*, pitches *p_1, ..., p_k* are played with velocities *v_1,...,v_k* then I define the vector by saying *p_i*-th entry is the duration of how long this pitch is played, and *2p_i*-th entry is the velocity and the last entry is reserved for the time *t*.

Comment: Dear @Bunlong Lay, could you describe more precisely what you mean by "my data look ugly"? And what is your objective? It will be much helpful to answer you :)

Comment: thanks I edited my post